# Batching up a filestream reader to send to RX

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I want to load the contents of a file line by line into a stream, and then sit there watching every second for new entries in the file - so a real time file reader that pipes the output to RX.

I have achieved this by reading one line at a time and if there is data on the readline(), to call back via an action passed in, which in the caller, puts the data on a ReplaySubject for RX subscribers.

The problem is this only sends back one line at a time on the RX stream. I would like to batch them up so it doesn't call back until you either have say 10 items to send back, or a certain time has passed - eg 5-10 seconds.

My callback is a collection of data, right now I have hard coded it to only return a single item in the collection as I can't figure out how to do the time-based batching.

can anyone suggest how to achieve this?

My code so far

```
public void StartFileWatcher(Action<LogTailMessage[]> callbackAction, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var wh = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            var fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(_path)
            {
                Filter = _file,
                EnableRaisingEvents = true
            };
            fsw.Changed += (s, e) => wh.Set();

            var lineNumber = 1;
            var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(_path, _file), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && !_isCancelled)
                {
                    var s = sr.ReadLine();
                    if (s != null)
                    {
                        //todo - batch these up so we only call back once we have 10 items, or if a certain amount of time has passed, send what we have
                        callbackAction(new [] {new LogTailMessage(lineNumber, s)});
                        lineNumber++;
                    }
                    else
                        wh.WaitOne(1000);
                }
            }
        }
```

Updated: Buffer solution

```
var watcherSubject = new ReplaySubject<LogTailMessage>();

            var watcher = new LogFileWatcher(path, filename);

            new TaskFactory().StartNew(() => watcher.StartFileWatcher(data => watcherSubject.OnNext(data), _cts.Token));

            Stream = watcherSubject
                .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), 20)
                .Where(d => d != null)
                .Replay()
                .RefCount();
```

And the filewatcher

```
public void StartFileWatcher(Action<LogTailMessage> callbackAction, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var wh = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            var fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(_path)
            {
                Filter = _file,
                EnableRaisingEvents = true
            };
            fsw.Changed += (s, e) => wh.Set();

            var fileName = Path.Combine(_path, _file);

            var startLine = GetFileStartLine(fileName);

            var lineNumber = 1;
            var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(_path, _file), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && !_isCancelled)
                {
                    var s = sr.ReadLine();
                    if (s != null)
                    {
                        if (lineNumber >= startLine)
                            callbackAction(new LogTailMessage(lineNumber, s));

                        lineNumber++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        wh.WaitOne(1000);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a lot of working in your original code that you really don't need to, and you're creating disposables and event handlers that aren't being cleaned up with.

You can really do the whole thing in a couple of observables.

To start with you need to watch for changes in the file. here's how:

```
IObservable<Unit> fileSystemWatcherChanges =
    Observable
        .Using(() =>
            new FileSystemWatcher(_path)
            {
                Filter = _file,
                EnableRaisingEvents = true
            },
            fsw =>
                Observable
                    .FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(
                        h => fsw.Changed += h, h => fsw.Changed -= h)
                    .Select(x => Unit.Default));
```

Now you need to open a stream and read from the stream every time the file changes:

```
IObservable<LogTailMessage> messages =
    Observable
        .Using(
            () => new FileStream(Path.Combine(_path, _file), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite),
            fs =>
                Observable
                    .Using(
                        () => new StreamReader(fs),
                        sr =>
                            fileSystemWatcherChanges
                                .StartWith(Unit.Default)
                                .Select(x =>
                                    Observable
                                        .Defer(() => Observable.FromAsync(() => sr.ReadLineAsync()))
                                        .Repeat()
                                        .TakeUntil(w => w == null))
                                .Merge()
                                .Where(w => w != null)))
        .Select((x, n) => new LogTailMessage(n, x));

IObservable<IList<LogTailMessage>> buffered =
    messages
        .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 10);
```

I tested this on my computer and I believe it gives the results that you need.

It's a complete Rx pipeline so if you subscribe like `IDisposable subscription = buffered.Subscribe();` and you later call `subscription.Dispose();` then it'll all clean up after itself.

And it avoids subjects.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, really interesting. Just a couple of questions for my understanding. What is the Defer() in there to do? Is the merge because you end up with an Observable of Observables, so you need to flatten it down to a single stream? And what determines the data types of (x, n)? ReadLineAsync just returns a string so after merge I thought you would get an Observable of string, so not sure where the int is coming from?

Comment: Also I need to adapt it so the initial file content is loaded and sent as one large block of LogTailData[] in a single observable tick, then the buffering for updates needs to continue after that, as well as specifying what point in the file to begin from (only the last 1000 lines for example) so you don't return the whole file since the beginning. I'll have a play and see what I can come up with but if you have any suggestions that would be great too

Comment: @NZJames - Tery taking out the `Defer` and see what happens. In a lot of cases I've seen the `FromAsync`/`Repeat` combo just repeat the first value returned from the async. The `Defer` ensures that the calls are always repeated.

Comment: @NZJames - Why does the initial load need to be like that?

Comment: The initial load could be 25k lines, which in batches of 100 via signalR takes far too long, so sending the initial load as a single message fixes that issue. One other thing though, running this and switching between a few log files one after another, within 30-60 seconds the stream closes down with an exception on the ReadLineAsync, message is "The stream is currently in use by a previous operation on the stream.". Trying to work out why this would be called more than once. The StreamReader is scoped to that Observable so can't see how else it would be called

Comment: Posted another question with the issue in more detail - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57004974/filestream-to-rx-throwing-invalidoperationexception

Comment: I tried to test this but when I set 5 seconds for the first parameter in `Buffer` method and update the file I get `InvalidOperationException: The stream is currently in use by a previous operation on the stream`.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `Buffer` on the subject:

```cs
var subject = ReplaySubject<LogTailMessage>();
StartFileWatcher(a => a.ToList().ForEach(ltm => subject.OnNext(ltm)), CancellationToken.None);
bufferedSubject = subject.Buffer (TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 10);
```

Comment: Just a question, I tried using Buffer but if I for example add three lines to the file being watched, I get three ticks on the subscriber, each tick containing ALL three lines - rather than one tick with the three lines. What have I done wrong? Updated the question above to show my solution

Comment: Seems to be ok most of the time... just happened once - could be related to something else. Just to confirm does the above solution look correct?

Comment: It looks correct, though you have two `ReplaySubject`s with infinite caching which will likely lead to a memory problem (unless you're ditching the subjects at some point).